# Can you use drbd8 for syncing more than two machines?

Tags: drbd

I'm really new to this. I've been struggling with how to keep multiple webservers synced. It seems like DRBD8 and OCFS2 is the way to go. However, every example I see so far keeps referencing dual-primary and two nodes. I don't see anything indicating this is the way to go for say 5-10 webservers. So the question is mostly, can DRBD8 be used to sync 5-10 web servers and would it be good in an environment were we frequently add/remove web servers?

Comment: http://www.drbd.org/users-guide/s-pacemaker-stacked-resources.html#s-pacemaker-stacked-4way

Comment: https://www.suse.com/documentation/sle_ha/singlehtml/book_sleha_techguides/book_sleha_techguides.html

Comment: DRBD is not the best tool for that job.  For web servers I would recommend a shared storage backend like NFS.  DRBD would be useful in setting up two mirrored NFS servers.  That way if one fails, the other will pick up the slack.  (It's not that easy, you still need to set up Heartbeat, Pacemaker, Keepalived, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

DRBD 8.x does only support two nodes, if you count the stacking option, it's up to 4 nodes. So it's not a solution for syncing data of 5-10 webservers. The upcoming DRBD version 9 will support up to 32 nodes. Another solution would be to use a cluster file system like GFS or GlusterFS, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustered_file_system